# Breakpoints Don't Hit in Visual Studio Code - What am I Doing Wrong

Tags: javascript, breakpoints

For some reason my VSC breakpoints don't hit. I am not sure why. My launch.json file has

```
{
    "type": "chrome",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
    "url": "http://localhost:8080",
    "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "file":"${workspaceFolder}/index.html"
}
```

I can set breakpoints in my JavaScript code. They show up (correctly) with red dots over on the left. However, they don't hit. Please note that I am only using JavaScript, not TypeScript.

I tried a bunch of changes to my launch.json file and tried moving my JavaScript files around. Nothing worked.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: One YouTube video suggested installing Live Server and switching to port 5500. I did both and it didn't help.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, I think the feature's just for Node? Use the browser's debugger and breakpoints instead.

Comment: Microsoft says that VSC can be used for browser debugging. See "Browser debugging in VS Code" (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/browser-debugging). Sadly I can't get it to work.

Answer (score -2):

Some folks at Microsoft suggested that I remove the "url" key from my launch.json file. That did the trick for me, at least.